# How to add roles in memory storage

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

I am creating an MVC 4 sample app.  I just want to use in memory storage.  So in memory storage, rather than using a persistent data store like a database.  Just wondering is it possible to have roles?

Usually I have roles defined in the database and then I use the authorize decoration, but how to do that when its just mock repositories

Comment: Maybe write a custom role provider that uses your mock repositories?

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See [Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts). I've edited your title. See [Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/130208/158100) where the consensus is "no, they should not".